# How to solve the issue of postback through browsers reload button in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a page in ASP.NET/C# where the user's information is saved to the database.
There are many fields on the page and when the validations are done then the information is saved.

The submission of information is done using an ASP.NET button.
The primary key of the table is generated in code itself, that is, every time it is increased by one.

I just faced an issue while reloading the page through the browser's reload button. I noticed that the same user information was submitted with the primary key value incremented by one.

So my question is how should I tackle this issue?
Should I just clear values of all textboxes after successful submission of data so that it will validate and then the user has to fill the information again?

Please share your ideas as to how can I handle this.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Sorry about it , I am asking this question from home.My work is saved in my office.Still I save info using Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing to do use use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, where after a postback where you have inserted the row, you redirect the user back to a page where they can view the item.  This way, if they press Refresh, it will just refresh the view page.

For example:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   // Insert Data
   ...

   // Redirect to get
   Response.Redirect("ViewItem.aspx?id=" + insertedItemId);
}
```

NB: They can still press back and submit again, but this is usually confirmed by the browser before resubmitting.

Comment: @Richard My worry is that they can still submit the info.What if we dont show the info just after the submit.

Comment: They can't submit the info as they're on a new page now, which doesn't have the form.  Yes, they can press back and resubmit, but the browser will ask for confirmation.  Hiding the form without redirecting to another page will NOT solve the refresh problem, as the refresh button simply sends the same as it did last time, regardless of what's still visible on the page.

Comment: @Richard You are right they can refresh and browser asks confirmationagain and if the user confirms then again the same info will be resubmitted.So can I not clear all textbox and dropdownlist values so that when he submits again the validation fails.I am just asking.

Comment: I think you're missing something.  If you're suggesting not using P/R/G and staying on the same page after you submit, you can clear the boxes, and this will stop them pressing submit again.  However, if they press F5, this doesn't care what's on the form - it simply submits the last thing again.  Redirecting to a GET page would remove or clear the form automatically, and pressing F5 wouldn't resubmit the form either.

Comment: @Richard Absolutely.I should think about redirecting to other page.Thanks a lot for sharing your thoughts.